Linear optimization objective with little-o notation in constraint
I am trying to solve a problem related to matrix decomposition. In essence, it is a maximin problem of the following form
$$ \max_x \min_{j} \left[f_{j=1}^{(n)}(x),f_{j=2}^{(n)}(x),...\right]$$
where each $f_j^{(n)}(x)$ is a (different) linear function of $x$ (i.e. we have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and the typical linearity properties are fulfilled) and $n$ is the number of rows in the input matrix. I know how to solve this problem in its unconstrained form. However, a further complication arises because the runtime of a subsequent step in the matrix decomposition depends on $x$ and $n$. To permit an efficiently computable solution, the following constraint must hold
$$x = o(n)$$
or equivalently $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}=0$. This means that $x$ must be a sublinear function of $n$.
Question: How do I solve such an optimization problem with a limit (little o notation) in a constraint? I have no experience with this situation.
